# How to use Google maps V3 with GLocalSearch Concept

Tags: php, google-maps

I want to add the redo search feature of google maps on this [SITE](http://www.airbnb.com/search#modified=true). Any idea how to populate result markers and listings the way these people have done it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example [here](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/localsearch/places.html) (check the source), but seems that V3 uses the [Places](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) library instead of focus on the GLocalSearch, see an example [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search) (check the source). It is really easy to implement, but the database seems sparse, and I could find few results compared with the "query loc: Place name".

Using GLocalSearch with V3 gave me even less results than using Places library, what is even more frustrating. Anyway, you can give a try.